# Clipboard isn't accessible

Tags: r, dataframe, clipboard

Here is my question:
I am trying my hand at datapasta(). I was able to do everything required but my finish result is not good.
How do I make my clipboard accessible so that I can copy what I need right into the clipboard instead of having to paste my copied text into the text box and then press saves to import my data? I believe this is the problem that is stopping me from properly viewing my copied data.frame correctly when I run head()

Here are the steps I followed via code chunk

> 

```
    install.packages("datapasta")
   test<-data.frame(
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                check.names = FALSE,
  `Pos  Team    P   W   D   L   GD  Pts` = c("1\tChelsea\t7\t5\t1\t1\t12\t16",
                                "2\tLiverpool\t7\t4\t3\t0\t15","3\tManchester City\t7\t4\t3\t0\t11\t14",
                                "4\tManchester United\t7\t4\t2\t1\t8\t14",
                                "5\tEverton\t7\t4\t2\t1\t5\t14",
                                "6\tBrighton\t7\t4\t2\t1\t3\t14","7\tBrentford\t7\t3\t3\t1\t4\t12",
                                "8\tTottenham\t7\t4\t0\t3\t12",
                                "9\tWest Ham\t7\t3\t2\t2\t4\t11",
                                "10\tAston Villa\t7\t3\t1\t3\t10","11\tArsenal\t7\t3\t1\t3\t10",
                                "12\tWolves\t7\t3\t0\t4\t9",
                                "13\tLeicester City\t7\t2\t2\t3\t8","14\tCrystal Palace\t7\t1\t4\t2\t7",
                                "15\tWatford\t7\t2\t1\t4\t7",
                                "16\tLeeds United\t7\t1\t3\t3\t6","17\tSouthampton\t7\t0\t4\t3\t4",
                                "18\tBurnley\t7\t0\t3\t4\t3",
                                "19\tNewcastle\t7\t0\t3\t4\t3","20\tNorwich City\t7\t0\t1\t6\t1")
)
head(test)
```

Here is my result which is not what I wanted

```
    Pos\tTeam\tP\tW\tD\tL\tGD\tPts
1          1\tChelsea\t7\t5\t1\t1\t12\t16
2            2\tLiverpool\t7\t4\t3\t0\t15
3  3\tManchester City\t7\t4\t3\t0\t11\t14
4 4\tManchester United\t7\t4\t2\t1\t8\t14
5           5\tEverton\t7\t4\t2\t1\t5\t14
6          6\tBrighton\t7\t4\t2\t1\t3\t14
>
```

[This is what pops up on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jmPB.png)

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know datapasta or what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but whenever I'm trying to copy a dataframe from R to something like excel, I like the clipr package. So I would use something like ```clipr::write_clip(test)``` which would copy it into my clipboard, so maybe that can help you: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/clipr/versions/0.7.1

Comment: What OS and R version are you using? Are you using RStudio?

Comment: @Silentdevildoll Ok thank you I will try this. Here is some info on datapasta https://github.com/MilesMcBain/datapasta

Comment: I am using the cloud version of R @MrFlick

Comment: Do you're running RStudio in your web browser? For security reasons, web browsers can't easily interact with your clipboard in the same way a native application can. Packages like `datapasta` just aren't as helpful in the cloud. Perhaps you can talk more explicitly about the problem you are trying to solve rather than the tool you are trying to use to solve it.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok I see, I am using the cloud.  I do not have any particular problem I am trying to solve at the moment. I was just playing around with it and seeing how I can utilize it for future projects. Thank you for making this clear to me.